# Intermittent 500 Error on Laravel Forge Server Running Octane with Fresh Laravel Install

Tags: laravel

This is really weird! I have a fresh install of Laravel deployed through Laravel Forge with Laravel Octane installed and I keep getting intermittent 500 errors like every other page refresh. You can see for yourself here: https://salestweet.com

**What I've Tried**

- Turning it off an on again. Problem persists
- Looking at Laravel logs. Nothing.
- Looking at Nginx logs. Nothing.
- Checking memory usage. Only using 50% of small server.

**Details of Setup**

- Server is standard 2GB virtual server on Linode
- Using Cloudflare for DNS
- Server has other sites on it that seem to work fine
- PHP 8.2
- Everything else is just as standard/default as it can be

Any suggestions? What could be causing this? Every other repo I've deployed with Forge and Octane has worked like a champ!

**Update**

I checked the PHP-FPM logs and I see this over and over again:

```
[04-Apr-2023 15:46:51] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[04-Apr-2023 15:46:51] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[04-Apr-2023 15:46:51] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 92897
[04-Apr-2023 15:46:51] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[04-Apr-2023 15:46:51] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

It looks like this is happening anywhere from every few seconds to every few minutes. Is this where I should be looking?

Comment: try using tools like ***ping*** or ***traceroute*** to check for connectivity issues between your server and the client.sometimes can be caused by network issues, such as intermittent connectivity or DNS resolution problems. Did you check the php logs as well?

Comment: Thanks, @charindu, for your suggestions. I've pinged the server and everything looks good with ping. The traceroute looks fine as much as I can tell too. I did update the original question with the PHP logs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reaching out to the Laravel Forge customer support and they suggested that I upgrade my Laravel Octane package from 1.5.2 to 1.5.3, which I did. Everything works as expected now. Thanks Nuno!